# Unable to Copy cURL from Chrome DevTools' Network Tool (Unable to Right-click on Links)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Version       : 111.0.5563.64 (正式版本) (arm64)
OS                   : Ventura 13.2.1
I am unable to copy cURL from Chrome DevTools' Network Tool because I am unable to right-click on links. This is preventing me from easily replicating requests in my terminal, which is a crucial part of my development workflow.

Steps to Reproduce:

Open Chrome DevTools and navigate to the Network tab.
Make a network request.
Attempt to right-click on the request link and select "Copy > Copy as cURL".
Expected Behavior:

The cURL command for the request should be copied to my clipboard.

Actual Behavior:

I am unable to right-click on the request link, preventing me from accessing the "Copy as cURL" option.

I have tried to solve this problem but I am still unable to resolve the issue. Has anyone faced a similar problem before, or does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have faced the same problem in same OS and Chrome version. Everything works in incognito mode but not in regular mode.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1425024

Comment: This issue has been resolved for me after updating the chrome to Version 111.0.5563.110

Answer (score 0):

I found this copy function has been moved to previous "Name" section, not available on "Headers, Payload, Preview, ..." section. Please right-click on the item listed in "Name" section, and select "Copy", "Copy link address". My Chrome version is 119.0.6045.160.